# Mercurial suddenly thinks all files have changed - waiting for lock on working directory

Tags: mercurial

I've been using Mercurial v 1.1 for several months to version documents and other files.  Yesterday it suddenly failed with the message:

```
waiting for lock on working directory
```

This happens in all projects I have under .hg control.  Mercurial also thinks that all files in all projects have changed.

There is no .hg/store/lock file in the project it says it is waiting on the lock for.

The only thing that could have caused this is that Windows installed security patch on my computer overnight.

Has anyone else seen this with Mercurial?

Answer (score 15):

I've had success by deleting that file `.hg/wlock` entirely if it exists, then everything is back to normal. If you are worried about losing something, just make a copy

Answer (score 9):

For working directory, the lock is `.hg/wlock`. Does the file exists?
For rebuilding the dirstate (beware it won't restore changes like adds/remove/renames/copies), you can use `hg debugrebuildstate`.

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded to hg version 1.3.1 and everything works now.

I must have had corruption in the 1.1.1 binaries (from Cygwin).

Cygwin is still on 1.1.

Answer (score 0):

To find out which file is locking the directory, in your working directory:

```
hg debuglocks
```

This should give a result indicating which file is locking the directory e.g.

```
lock: free
wlock: (461232s)
```

To unlock use force:

```
hg debuglocks --force-wlock
```

or:

```
hg debuglocks --force-lock
```

for more information:

```
hg debuglocks -h
```

Note this paragraph:

> Locks protect the integrity of Mercurial's data, so should be treated
>   with care. System crashes or other interruptions may cause locks to
>   not be properly released, though Mercurial will usually detect and
>   remove such stale locks automatically.